# Kendo scheduler not getting rendered as expected

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using Kendo Scheduler and most of the time it renders in some unexpected format, screen shots are attached for both the Expected and unexpected.[image: Unexpected]

[image: Unexpected 2]

[image: Expected]

Comment: If you post the code that you use to include the scheduler we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
eventually I found the solution, it caused due to wrong jQuery version I used. I used 1.8.1 which caused the issue and using 1.9.1 solved the issue.

Thanks
Rk_Hirpara